# find Ip address in my network

Tags: c#

how to find all ipaddress in my intra network juz like IPMSG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enumerate All of the IP Addresses on the Network W/O ActiveDirectory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ipaddresses.aspx) should have the info you require. The code is in C#.

Read the comments on the article for some additional ideas.

Comment: Seeing this question and your answer I thought you might be able to help me. How would you search for all available SQL Server instances on a network?

Comment: The SqlDataSourceEnumerator class might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx